# Dialog for incoming bluetooth request

Tags: android, bluetooth, request, handler

In my application two devices are connected via bluetooth. In the background runs an own thread for the bluetooth connection. (Just like the [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer) )
When one device wants to connect to another device i want a request dialog to be displayed on the second device.
So I guess that i have to modify the AcceptThread. The AcceptThread has to inform my mainThread (for example with a Handler).

In the AcceptThread I find this code:

```
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
```

Now here is my problem: this "blocking call" runs the whole time. How and when shall I inform my mainThread that another device wants to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely afterwards.
What you want is the result of the blocking call - of the *.accept()*. 
That is *socket* in your code.

Here is a quote from the Android BluetoothServerSocket documentation:

> Then call accept() to listen for incoming connection requests. This
>   call will block until a connection is established, at which point, it
>   will return a BluetoothSocket to manage the connection. Once the
>   BluetoothSocket is acquired, it's a good idea to call close() on the
>   BluetoothServerSocket when it's no longer needed for accepting
>   connections. Closing the BluetoothServerSocket will not close the
>   returned BluetoothSocket.

So don't forget to do:

```
 mmServerSocket.close()
```

After you receive a socket correctly - a [BluetoothSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html) actually -, you can choose what to do with it following the user's choice:

- Should he go ahead, you just create the AsyncTask that reads from the socket until the AsyncTask is cancelled or an Exception occurs(on Bluetooth disconnect probably).
- Should he decline, just cancel the socket

If you receive an Exception during the blocking call I would return to the main menu only a toast, saying something failed. But you can do a dialog (like retry?)